# how to show date and time in phpfox

Tags: php, html, sql, phpfox

how to show date and time in phpfox

```
{$aSample.post_date|date:'core.global_update_time'}
```

this html code shows

January 1, 1970

this time only not the correct date and time from sql table

I want like this view

Monday, July 15, 2013 8:59 am

or

July 15, 2013 20:01:03

Answer (score 1):

Create a new setting from here(`?do=/admincp/setting/add/`) containing value `"F m,Y H:i:s"` and replace `'core.global_update_time'` with new setting name